# Sorting SLD file for BGS Digimap provided by Edina?

Tags: qgis, sld, united-kingdom, edina

Does anyone know how to sort the sld files provided here:

http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/geology/using_data_with_gis/legend_files.htm

The reason I ask is that I only want to display the appropriate types in the legend under Qgis.  At the moment all of the rock types appear to be displayed.

Unfortunately I can't access the LYR file provided by BGS with Qgis.

Comment: I use BGS 625k shapefiles with the SLD files provided by the site you mention, without problems. Not sure what you mean about displaying just the appropriate types in the legend. Do you want to display all of the shapes on the map but legends only for selected ones?

Comment: The SLD file colours the map Ok, but when I use the Qgis print set up. The legend option seems to pull in  everything for the UK even when it is not relevant for the area in question.

Comment: I confirm this problem. Even if a small subset is cut and saved to a new shapefile then styled using the SLD file all of the formations for the whole of GB appear in the legend. Sorry, I just can't find a way of limiting the legend items to only the objects shown on the print composer canvas. Anyone?

Comment: Would there be away of marrying up the rock types from the attributes table to those in the sld manually?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. By the look of it in the composer the rocks on the map canvas appear at the top of the legend (apart from a number of rogues) so I suppose it would be possible to delete the ones not required. But what a job. N.

Comment: I've been touch with the BGS, but they don't produce sld's yet.  In the end I had to manually transcribe the details from a Qgis project opened with the sld produced by Edina to that I had from the BGS- I don't want to do that again!